# How to use datareader in C#?

Tags: c#

Where I make mistake please tell me....
When I click on insert button it shows me this message

> Registration No. Already Exists Try Another.

But i tried new registration number every time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   
{  
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from studentreg where registrationno='" + txtrgno.Text + "'";
cn.Open();
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())  
{  
MessageBox.Show("Registration No. Already Exists Try Another", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK,     MessageBoxImage.Error);
txtrgno.Text = "";
txtrgno.Focus();
if ((dr != null))  
{  
dr.Close();
}  
return;  
}  
//cn.Close();  
try  
{  
string gen="";  
if(rdb1_m.IsChecked==true)  
{  
gen="Male";  
}  
else if(rdb2_f.IsChecked==true)  
{  
gen="Female";  
}  
string filename = "";  
FileStream fs;  
byte[] x=null;  
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) == false)  
{  
fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);  
x = br.ReadBytes((int)(fs.Length));  
}  
cmd.Connection = cn;
SqlParameter p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18,     p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, p26, p27, p28, p29, p30, p31, p32, p33;
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into studentreg values(@rgno1, @sname1, @dob1, @bloodgroup1, @gender1, @imark11, @imark12, @photo1, @fname1, @fq1, @fo1, @mname1, @mq1, @mo1, @mton1, @religion1, @nationality1, @state1, @distric1, @mobile1, @email1, @caddr1, @paddr1, @academicy1, @adclass1, @adsec1, @addate1, @lschool1, @lclass1, @pyear1, @estudent1, @eclass1, @esec1)";  
p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@rgno1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sname1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob1", SqlDbType.Date);  
p4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@bloodgroup1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);  
p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);  
p6 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@imark11", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p7 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@imark12", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p8 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@photo1", SqlDbType.Image);  
p9 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p10 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fq1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p11 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@fo1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
p12 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p13 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mq1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p14 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mo1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p15 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mton1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);  
p16 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@religion1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);  
p17 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@nationality1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);  
p18 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@state1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p19 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@distric1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p20 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile1", SqlDbType.BigInt);  
p21 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@email1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p22 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@caddr1", SqlDbType.VarChar);  
p23 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@paddr1", SqlDbType.VarChar);  
p24 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@academicy1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);  
p25 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@adclass1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);  
p26 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@adsec1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);  
p27 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@addate1", SqlDbType.Date);
p28 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lschool1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p29 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@lclass1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);  
p30 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pyear1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
p31 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@estudent1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);  
p32 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@eclass1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);  
p33 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@esec1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);  
cn.Open();  
p1.Value = txtrgno.Text;  
p2.Value = txt_sname.Text;  
p3.Value = dtp_dob.Text;  
p4.Value = cmbx1_bloodgrp.Text;  
p5.Value = gen;  
p6.Value = txt_idm1.Text;  
p7.Value = txt_idm2.Text;  
p8.Value = x;  
p9.Value = txt_fname.Text;  
p10.Value = txt_fq.Text;  
p11.Value = txt_fo.Text;  
p12.Value = txt_mname.Text;  
p13.Value = txt_mq.Text;  
p14.Value = txt_mo.Text;  
p15.Value = txt_tongue.Text;  
p16.Value = txt_religion.Text;  
p17.Value = txt_nationality.Text;  
p18.Value = txt_state.Text;  
p19.Value = txt_dist.Text;  
p20.Value = txt_mobile.Text;  
p21.Value = txt_email.Text;  
p22.Value = txt_caddr.Text;  
p23.Value = txt_paddr.Text;  
p24.Value = cmbx2_academicyear.Text;  
p25.Value = cmbx3_class.Text;  
p26.Value = cmbx4_section.Text;  
p27.Value = dtp_admissiondate.Text;  
p28.Value = txt_pschool.Text;  
p29.Value = cmbx7_pclass.Text;  
p30.Value = cmbx8_pyear.Text;  
p31.Value = txt_esname.Text;  
p32.Value = cmbx5_eclass.Text;  
p33.Value = cmbx6_esec.Text;  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
cn.Close();  
MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Inserted");  
}  
catch(SqlException ex)   
{  
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
}  
cn.Close();   
}
```

Comment: `SqlParameter p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, .... p33;` You are doing it wrong...

Comment: tell me the correct solution Kamil

Comment: Please take more time to format your code when posting - and reduce your problem to a *short* but complete example. You really don't need 33 parameters to demonstrate the issue...

Comment: You could simplify by using [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the parameters.

Comment: @WasimKhan You should learn to use `DataTable` object and just use Insert method - instead of so many lines of code. What are you doing is ancient method. You can be much more productive with C#.NET.

Comment: #Kamil comment me right code which you told. because i m a beginner .

Comment: Just read about DataTable. Maybe you can find some videos about this on Youtube. I will not explain something that was explained many times on many websites and tutorials.

Comment: @theMayer: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Well, I might argue that we should stop using `SQL Server` for the same reason, but that is a discussion for a different day.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `cmd.ExecuteReader();` which will return one row for your `SELECT` statement, since it uses `COUNT(*)`. Now this could return `0` count or more than one.

You need to call [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then check the returned value.

Something like:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

if(count > 0)
{
   // Already exists
}
```

**But more importantly,** you should parametrized your `SELECT` query as well. Also make sure to enclose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` object in [`using` statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), since your first query is based on string concatenation and it is prone to SQL injection.

Your first part of code should be like:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    using (
        SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("select count(*) from studentreg where registrationno = @registrationNumber", cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@registrationNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = txtrgno.Text});
        //or
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registrationNumber", txtregno.Text);
        cn.Open();

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            // Already exists
            MessageBox.Show("Registration No. Already Exists Try Another", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            txtrgno.Text = "";
            txtrgno.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need parens on the ExecuteScalar